# How to refresh service worker when new update is pushed on server

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, service-worker-events, craco

I have a react app created by craco, it have service worker registered.
After pushing new build to server, user is still getting old data / build files as they are cached by service worker.
How can i force refresh the webpage, or give popup to user to refresh the page.

I tried using the existing code in onstatechange method which says -

New content is available and will be used when all tabs for this page are closed.

But this message pops up even if i change the state to offline.

Please suggest on how it can be achieved without forcing to close all tabs.